# rich:tooltip for command button

Tags: richfaces

I am using richfaces 4.0 and I want to be able to get a tooltip to appear when the mouse hovers over a button. I have a tooltip working for a panel but nothing is appearing for me when i try do this for the button Here is the code i have:

```
<a4j:outputPanel id="tooltippanel"> 
<h:commandButton id="SubmitToolButton" value="Log Out Tool" action="index.xhtml" style="FONT-WEIGHT: bold; height : 40px; width : 160px; margin-left:710px; font-size:12px" 
    actionListener="#{userData.getlogOutTool}" >
    <rich:tooltip for="SubmitToolButton" styleClass="tooltip" layout="block" mode="ajax" value="Submit">
                         Submitting tools
                </rich:tooltip>
    </h:commandButton>
</a4j:outputPanel>
```

any help would be great. thanks.

Comment: Try wrapping `h:commandButton` and `rich:tooltip` into `a4j:outputPanel`.

Comment: @VasilLukach i tried what you said and still nothing. above is the code

Comment: It works fine. I have tested your code in my project (with commented or changed actionListener) and it display tooltip as expected. If it not work for you, than problem is not in this code.

Comment: The rich:tooltip "for" attribute ("target" in newer RichFaces) used in your example is wrong (belongs to the h:commandButton). It should be the "id" of the a4j:outputPanel, see  my full answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `h:commandButton` and `rich:tooltip` into `a4j:outputPanel`

Answer (score 0):

As Vasil suggested you need to embed in an **a4j:outputPanel**. You can have two options depend on where you place the **rich:tooltip** element.

One option is adding **rich:tooltip** element as a child of the **h:commandButton** element but in this case you need to pay attention targeting to the **a4j:outputPanel** element and not the **h:commandButton** element as you did in your example. Here is the proper way:

```
<a4j:outputPanel id="tooltippanel">
   <h:commandButton id="SubmitToolButton" ...>
      <rich:tooltip target="tooltippanel" ...>
         ...
      </rich:tooltip>
    </h:commandButton>
</a4j:outputPanel>
```

The other option is adding **rich:tooltip** element as a child of the **a4j:outputPanel** directly sibling to the **h:commandButton** element. In this case you need not to use the target attribute:

```
<a4j:outputPanel>
   <h:commandButton id="SubmitToolButton" .../>
   <rich:tooltip ...>
         ...
   </rich:tooltip>
</a4j:outputPanel>
```

Perhaps the second option is preferable because you need not to use so called **"magic id"** for the **a4j:outputPanel** element.

I am using RichFaces 4.3.7 where the **for** attribute is not exists in **rich:tooltip** element that is why I have used **target** attribute.